# forward protocol @required to subclasses

Tags: objective-c

I have:

```
@interface SuperClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

And then

```
@interface SubClass : SuperClass
```

This `SuperClass`does not have the required protocol methods implemented `SubClass` one does.
Is it possible to prevent the warnings (saying SuperClass implementation is incomplete)?

Instead of implementing empty/nil methods in `SuperClass`, can the @required warnings validation be made against `SubClass`?

Comment: You're looking for abstract classes in Objective-C. They don't exist. Are you sure you want a "is a" relationship, instead of a "has a"? It seems more in keeping with the grain.

Comment: We can say I wanted to remake UITableViewController. If you subclass UITableViewController you don't declare UITableView protocols but you have to implement them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what you're asking for is essentially abstract classes, which don't exist in Objective-C.

Your best bet is to stub the methods in the base class to throw an exception of some kind.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was looking for some sort of abstract classes in obj-c. As I didn't find anything I was hoping there was some way to "forward" the protocol methods, maybe redefining the @protocol in SuperClass.h (which I couldn't get to work). Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 10):

You might not declare protocol adoption in the superclass, but demand compliance in all subclasses. This can be done by implementing `+initialize` in your superclass as follows:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
  if (self != [SuperClass class] && 
      ![self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITableViewDelegate)])
  {
    @throw [NSException ...]
  }
}
```

That way, whenever a subclass of `SuperClass` is initialized, it will throw an exception if it doesn't conform to `<UITableViewDelegate>`. This requires no further work after putting this in the superclass.

Comment: That one sounds nice, but I ended up going with Joshua's: implementing the required protocol methods with just one `@throw [NSException ...]` line. Since only 2 methods are required in this case, it saves adding the protocols to all subclasses as the super class name (not actually `SuperClass`) already implies it's a (custom)TableViewController. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Another (even lighter-weight) option would be to declare the methods in a category interface onto the base class (but provide no implementation). That way, the compiler will let you send those messages, but if your concrete subclasses don't actually respond to those messages, you'll get an exception automatically.

Comment: I prefer to send an explicit exception in these kind of cases, as a generic 'does not respond' can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If `SuperClass` is not conform to the `UITableViewDelegate`, etc. protocols it should not have it in the .h.

You can simply move the protocols to `SubClass`.

Comment: Yes, but I want all subclasses of `SuperClass` to implement them.

Comment: I think the response of Joshua is more appropriate : you want abstract classes, not available in Obj-C. The fact that `SuperClass` implement a protocol doesn't add any obligations for the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible using a private class extension.

**Example 1**

Superclass.h

```
@interface Superclass : UIViewController
@end
```

Superclass.m

```
@interface Superclass()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation Superclass
// implement interface methods
@end
```

Subclass.h

```
@interface Subclass : Superclass<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

Taking it a step further, you could move the private class extension into a private header Superclass+Private.h then your other internal classes can know it implements them too.

**Example 2**

Superclass+Private.h

```
#import "Superclass.h"

@interface Superclass()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

Superclass.m

```
#import "Superclass+Private.h>

@implementation Superclass
// implement interface methods
@end
```

**Note**
There is a limitation that this technique prevents you overriding and calling super in method that the subclass does not its super class has implemented. For those methods I would recommend the UIGestureRecogniser subclass pattern.